# HTML/CSS design for webpage

Tags: html, css

I am creating a webpage and I have 99% of the page done. For some reason, I can't figure out the HTML/CSS part of one minor feature. My design looks like this right now(attachment titled before picture):
[before picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBars.png)

I want it to look like this (attachment titled after picture). [after picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBobs.png)

As you can see, I have almost everything done, I just need to add a small grey box that says "Feature Presenter 1" and so forth above the picture but I can not figure out what the HTML/CSS should be. Can someone please modify my HTML/CSS code below so that it matches the after picture? Please someone help me, I am so close to completing the project. Thank you so much

The HTML is below:

```
<tr>
          <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background-color:#ffffff;"><table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:700px;" class="em_wrapper">
              <tr>
                <td width="18" style="width:18px;" class="em_side10">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="668" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:668px;" class="em_wrapper">
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="328" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="width:328px;" class="em_wrapper">
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="328" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:328px;" class="em_w300">
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top" height="189" style="height:189px;border: solid 2px #4d4d4d;  display:block; border-top-left-radius:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"  class="em_wrapper" >
                                            <tr>
                                              <td height="189" align="center" valign="bottom" style="height:189px;"><img src="https://tieitapp-cdn1.s3.amazonaws.com/home/tieit/domains/app.tieit.io/public_html/assets/img/email/026696a00d07148ec092a60c0cd8b8d3.png" width="145" alt="" height="163" style="display:block; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:30px; color:#000000; max-width:145px; height:163px;" class="em_g_img"  border="0" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </table></td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#4d4d4d" style="background-color:#4d4d4d; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px;"><table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper">
                                            <tr>
                                              <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0px 10px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                                  <tr>
                                                    <td class="em_white" align="center" valign="top"  style="font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; color:#ffffff;padding:8px 0px;  "><span style="font-weight:bold;">&lt;Name&gt;</span> <br />
                                                      &lt;Institution&gt;</td>
                                                  </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:11px;"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:125px;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#007f3d" style="border-radius:5px;"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:125px;">
                                                              <tr>
                                                                <td class="em_white" align="center" valign="middle" height="56" style="height:56px; font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold;  "><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; display:block; line-height:16px; ">View Participation<br />
                                                                  Options</a></td>
                                                              </tr>
                                                            </table></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                      </table></td>
                                                  </tr>
                                                </table></td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </table></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table></td>
                                  <td width="12" style="width:12px;" >&nbsp;</td>
                                  <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="border: solid 2px #4d4d4d;  display:block; border-top-left-radius:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"  class="em_wrapper" >
                                            <tr>
                                              <td height="189" style="height:189px;" align="center" valign="bottom"><img src="https://tieitapp-cdn1.s3.amazonaws.com/home/tieit/domains/app.tieit.io/public_html/assets/img/email/787e8651d36187721fdec8615b8e4463.png" width="145" alt="" height="159" style="display:block; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:30px; color:#000000; max-width:145px; height:159px;" class="em_g_img"  border="0" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </table></td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#4d4d4d" style="background-color:#4d4d4d; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px;"><table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper">
                                            <tr>
                                              <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0px 10px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                                  <tr>
                                                    <td class="em_white" align="center" valign="top"  style="font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; color:#ffffff;padding:8px 0px;  "><span style="font-weight:bold;">&lt;Name&gt;</span> <br />
                                                      &lt;Institution&gt;</td>
                                                  </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:11px;"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:125px;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#007f3d" style="border-radius:5px;"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:125px;">
                                                              <tr>
                                                                <td class="em_white" align="center" valign="middle" height="56" style="height:56px; font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold;  "><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; display:block; line-height:16px; ">View Participation<br />
                                                                  Options</a></td>
                                                              </tr>
                                                            </table></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                      </table></td>
                                                  </tr>
                                                </table></td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </table></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table width="328" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" style="width:328px;" class="em_wrapper">
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" class="em_ptop"><table width="328" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:328px;" class="em_w300">
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top" height="189" style="height:189px;border: solid 2px #4d4d4d;  display:block; border-top-left-radius:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"  class="em_wrapper" >
                                            <tr>
                                              <td height="189" style="height:189px;" align="center" valign="bottom"><img src="https://tieitapp-cdn1.s3.amazonaws.com/home/tieit/domains/app.tieit.io/public_html/assets/img/email/1c43c6297227649ba26e611381191ef9.png" width="145" alt="" height="153"  style="display:block; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:30px; color:#000000; max-width:145px; height:153px;" class="em_g_img"  border="0" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </table></td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#4d4d4d" style="background-color:#4d4d4d; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px;"><table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper">
                                            <tr>
                                              <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0px 10px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                                  <tr>
                                                    <td class="em_white" align="center" valign="top"  style="font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; color:#ffffff;padding:8px 0px;  "><span style="font-weight:bold;">&lt;Name&gt;</span> <br />
                                                      &lt;Institution&gt;</td>
                                                  </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:11px;"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:125px;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#007f3d" style="border-radius:5px;"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:125px;">
                                                              <tr>
                                                                <td class="em_white" align="center" valign="middle" height="56" style="height:56px; font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold;  "><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; display:block; line-height:16px; ">View Participation<br />
                                                                  Options</a></td>
                                                              </tr>
                                                            </table></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                      </table></td>
                                                  </tr>
                                                </table></td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </table></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table></td>
                                  <td width="12" style="width:12px;" >&nbsp;</td>
                                  <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top" height="189" style="height:189px;border: solid 2px #4d4d4d;  display:block; border-top-left-radius:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"  class="em_wrapper" >
                                            <tr>
                                              <td height="189" style="height:189px;" align="center" valign="bottom"><img src="https://tieitapp-cdn1.s3.amazonaws.com/home/tieit/domains/app.tieit.io/public_html/assets/img/email/887a206a411d8ffd17674ffda4b9a939.png" width="145" alt="" height="157" style="display:block; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:30px; color:#000000; max-width:145px; height:157px;" class="em_g_img"  border="0" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </table></td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#4d4d4d" style="background-color:#4d4d4d; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px;"><table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper">
                                            <tr>
                                              <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0px 10px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                                  <tr>
                                                    <td class="em_white" align="center" valign="top"  style="font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; color:#ffffff;padding:8px 0px;  "><span style="font-weight:bold;">&lt;Name&gt;</span> <br />
                                                      &lt;Institution&gt;</td>
                                                  </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:11px;"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:125px;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#007f3d" style="border-radius:5px;"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:125px;">
                                                              <tr>
                                                                <td class="em_white" align="center" valign="middle" height="56" style="height:56px; font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold;  "><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; display:block; line-height:16px; ">View Participation<br />
                                                                  Options</a></td>
                                                              </tr>
                                                            </table></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                      </table></td>
                                                  </tr>
                                                </table></td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </table></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
                <td width="14" style="width:14px;" class="em_side10">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- //four column section -->
```

THE CSS is below:

```
<style type="text/css">
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100% !important; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important; }
img { border: 0 !important; outline: none !important; }
td, a, span { border-collapse: collapse; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; }
.ExternalClass * { line-height: 100%; }
.em_defaultlink a { color: inherit !important; text-decoration: none !important; }
.em_black a { text-decoration: none; color: #000000; }
.em_white a { text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; }
.em_blue a { text-decoration: none; color: #0a75b1; }
.em_grey a { text-decoration: none; color: #4d4d4d; }
.em_g_img + div { display: none; }
 @media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:667px) {
.em_main_table { width: 100% !important; }
.em_wrapper { width: 100% !important; }
.em_hide { display: none !important; }
.em_full_img { width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; }
.em_full_img img { width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; }
.em_side10 { width: 10px !important; }
.em_ptop { padding-top: 20px !important; } /* Padding Left Right Bottom */
.em_h20 { height: 20px !important; font-size: 1px!important; line-height: 1px!important; }
.em_w300 { width: 320px !important; }
.em_w280 { width: 320px !important; }
.em_font_18 { font-size: 27px !important; line-height: 31px !important; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.em_main_table { width: 100% !important; }
.em_wrapper { width: 100% !important; }
.em_hide { display: none !important; }
.em_full_img { width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; }
.em_full_img img { width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; }
.em_side10 { width: 10px !important; }
.em_side_10 { width: 10px !important; }
.em_ptop { padding-top: 20px !important; } /* Padding Left Right Bottom */
.em_h20 { height: 20px !important; font-size: 1px!important; line-height: 1px!important; }
.em_font_18 { font-size: 18px !important; line-height: 23px !important; }
.em_w300 { width: 300px !important; } /* update the N number as per width */
.em_w280 { width: 300px !important; }
.em_w146 { width: 146px !important; }
.em_aside25 { padding: 0px 25px !important; }
u + .em_body .em_full_wrap { width: 100% !important; width: 100vw !important; }
}
</style>
```

Comment: your code is overkill

Comment: This kinda questions should be on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: There are many issues when it comes to best practices, with your code. The `table` tag should only be used for tabular data and not for layout. Next, avoid using `!important`, see: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used . Finally, Stackoverflow is a resource to assist with a specific issue with your code. Questions along the lines of "here is my code, please fix it" are not usually well recieved. Take the [tour]  and read the [help] for more info.

Comment: @JonP Good article, I learned something. Knew not to abuse `!important` but the examples of when it is acceptable is good.  Do you thing using it to override css libraries (like bootstrap) is ok? Like if you want part of class declaration but want to change something small like the color or font-size.

Comment: @JBis , in general if I was trying to override bootstrap I'd try for a more specific rule or if it is a global change, change the bootstrap variable. If I neither of those were an option, then I'd *consider* `!important`

Comment: @TheInfectedDrake Absolutely not! Code Review does not accept questions asking for help to add features or fix bugs. Please see [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what are you trying to do there. I can tell you it is not the right way to do it. Please try to implement [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). Right now I'm giving you the code you need for the sack of your question.

```
<tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background-color:#ffffff;"><table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:700px;" class="em_wrapper">
          <tr>
            <td width="18" style="width:18px;" class="em_side10">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="668" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:668px;" class="em_wrapper">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="328" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="width:328px;" class="em_wrapper">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="328" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:328px;" class="em_w300">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top"  style="border: solid 2px #9e9f9f;  display:block; "><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"  class="em_wrapper" >
                                        <tr><td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#9e9f9f" style="background-color:#9e9f9f; color:#fff;">Feature Presenter 1<table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper"></table></td></tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td height="189" align="center" valign="bottom" style="height:189px;"><img src="https://tieitapp-cdn1.s3.amazonaws.com/home/tieit/domains/app.tieit.io/public_html/assets/img/email/026696a00d07148ec092a60c0cd8b8d3.png" width="145" alt="" height="163" style="display:block; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:30px; color:#000000; max-width:145px; height:163px;" class="em_g_img"  border="0" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </table></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#4d4d4d" style="background-color:#4d4d4d; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px;"><table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper">
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0px 10px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                              <tr>
                                                <td class="em_white" align="center" valign="top"  style="font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; color:#ffffff;padding:8px 0px;  "><span style="font-weight:bold;">&lt;Name&gt;</span> <br />
                                                  &lt;Institution&gt;</td>
                                              </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:11px;"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:125px;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#007f3d" style="border-radius:5px;"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:125px;">
                                                          <tr>
                                                            <td class="em_white" align="center" valign="middle" height="56" style="height:56px; font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold;  "><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; display:block; line-height:16px; ">View Participation<br />
                                                              Options</a></td>
                                                          </tr>
                                                        </table></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </table></td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </table></td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </table></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table></td>
                              <td width="12" style="width:12px;" >&nbsp;</td>
                              <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="border: solid 2px #9e9f9f;  display:block; "><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"  class="em_wrapper" >
                                        <tr><td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#9e9f9f" style="background-color:#9e9f9f; color:#fff;">Feature Presenter 2<table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper"></table></td></tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td height="189" align="center" valign="bottom" style="height:189px;"><img src="https://tieitapp-cdn1.s3.amazonaws.com/home/tieit/domains/app.tieit.io/public_html/assets/img/email/787e8651d36187721fdec8615b8e4463.png" width="145" alt="" height="159" style="display:block; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:30px; color:#000000; max-width:145px; height:159px;" class="em_g_img"  border="0" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </table></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#4d4d4d" style="background-color:#4d4d4d; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px;"><table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper">
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0px 10px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                              <tr>
                                                <td class="em_white" align="center" valign="top"  style="font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; color:#ffffff;padding:8px 0px;  "><span style="font-weight:bold;">&lt;Name&gt;</span> <br />
                                                  &lt;Institution&gt;</td>
                                              </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:11px;"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:125px;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#007f3d" style="border-radius:5px;"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:125px;">
                                                          <tr>
                                                            <td class="em_white" align="center" valign="middle" height="56" style="height:56px; font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold;  "><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; display:block; line-height:16px; ">View Participation<br />
                                                              Options</a></td>
                                                          </tr>
                                                        </table></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </table></td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </table></td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </table></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="328" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" style="width:328px;" class="em_wrapper">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" class="em_ptop"><table width="328" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:328px;" class="em_w300">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="border: solid 2px #9e9f9f; "><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"  class="em_wrapper" >
                                        <tr><td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#9e9f9f" style="background-color:#9e9f9f; color:#fff;">Feature Presenter 3<table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper"></table></td></tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td height="189" align="center" valign="bottom" style="height:189px;"><img src="https://tieitapp-cdn1.s3.amazonaws.com/home/tieit/domains/app.tieit.io/public_html/assets/img/email/1c43c6297227649ba26e611381191ef9.png" width="145" alt="" height="153"  style="display:block; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:30px; color:#000000; max-width:145px; height:153px;" class="em_g_img"  border="0" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </table></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#4d4d4d" style="background-color:#4d4d4d; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px;"><table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper">
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0px 10px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                              <tr>
                                                <td class="em_white" align="center" valign="top"  style="font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; color:#ffffff;padding:8px 0px;  "><span style="font-weight:bold;">&lt;Name&gt;</span> <br />
                                                  &lt;Institution&gt;</td>
                                              </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:11px;"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:125px;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#007f3d" style="border-radius:5px;"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:125px;">
                                                          <tr>
                                                            <td class="em_white" align="center" valign="middle" height="56" style="height:56px; font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold;  "><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; display:block; line-height:16px; ">View Participation<br />
                                                              Options</a></td>
                                                          </tr>
                                                        </table></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </table></td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </table></td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </table></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table></td>
                              <td width="12" style="width:12px;" >&nbsp;</td>
                              <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="border: solid 2px #9e9f9f; "><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"  class="em_wrapper" >
                                        <tr><td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#4d4d4d" style="background-color:#9e9f9f; color:#fff;">Feature Presenter 4<table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper"></table></td></tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td height="189" align="center" valign="bottom" style="height:189px;"><img src="https://tieitapp-cdn1.s3.amazonaws.com/home/tieit/domains/app.tieit.io/public_html/assets/img/email/887a206a411d8ffd17674ffda4b9a939.png" width="145" alt="" height="157" style="display:block; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:30px; color:#000000; max-width:145px; height:157px;" class="em_g_img"  border="0" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </table></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#4d4d4d" style="background-color:#4d4d4d; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px;"><table width="157" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:157px;" class="em_wrapper">
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0px 10px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                              <tr>
                                                <td class="em_white" align="center" valign="top"  style="font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; color:#ffffff;padding:8px 0px;  "><span style="font-weight:bold;">&lt;Name&gt;</span> <br />
                                                  &lt;Institution&gt;</td>
                                              </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:11px;"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:125px;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#007f3d" style="border-radius:5px;"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:125px;">
                                                          <tr>
                                                            <td class="em_white" align="center" valign="middle" height="56" style="height:56px; font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold;  "><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; display:block; line-height:16px; ">View Participation<br />
                                                              Options</a></td>
                                                          </tr>
                                                        </table></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </table></td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </table></td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </table></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
            <td width="14" style="width:14px;" class="em_side10">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- //four column section -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Asif Arman. I am a new developer. I will research best practices for this. Thanks